# How I get value from URL to input form?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get value (TEXT) from URL to input from.

Example:

domain.com/page?code=123abc

I need to get 123abc paste automatically on input form with (code) id or name.

How I can do it with JS.

Thank you.

Need to use JavaScript

Comment: I'm sure you can use `URLSearchParams` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 2):

See [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');
```

then set as `.value` of the input.